# Average stock price of a company in a range of dates

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Recently in an interview I was asked a quite intriguing question.

Suppose we are given a large array of n objects where each object represents stock price of a company on a given date. Consider that there is no missing date in between and stock price stays constant through out the day for any given date. We want to find the average stock price between any 2 dates, i.e., for a given pair (startDate, endDate), with startDate < endDate.

Clearly there is an O(n) solution to the algorithm by traversing through the entire array to find the average. However, can we optimize the calculation, where we can probably store the data in some data structure or do some kind of pre-processing? The interviewer asked for an O(1) solution.

Comment: Here is the explanation and source code for this problem : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-sum-of-given-range/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure there is.  You can pre-process the array so that each element now stores the cumulative *sum* of the stock prices on that date and all previous dates; this pre-processing will take O(*n*) time for *n* dates.

Then, to calculate the average stock price across a given date range in O(1) time, you:

1. load the sums for the last day of the range and for the day before the beginning of the range from the array,
2. take their difference to obtain the sum of the stock prices over the date range, and
3. divide by the number of days in the range.

(If you're doing this with integer variables, it's possible that the cumulative sum may overflow and wrap around at some point.  This is actually (mostly) harmless, since the subtraction in step 2 will still give the correct result, as long as you never ask for the average across such a long range that even the sum over that range overflows.

With floats, you won't have to worry about overflow, but you'll slowly lose precision as the cumulative sum increases.  Thus, the results for later dates may be somewhat less precise.  This is still not likely to be a problem in practice, unless your stock price data goes back for centuries.)

BTW, if you're willing to accept an O(log *n*) query time, you could also solve this problem with a [segment tree](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/18051).  This is slower and more complicated, but has one advantage: it lets you also *modify* the price on any date in O(log *n*) time, as opposed to O(*n*) for the cumulative sum method.  Also, it doesn't suffer from the precision loss issue for long ranges.